# Run "NPM INSTALL" on Visual Studio Code threw error Error: Unsupported platform: Windows_NT x64 using Window 11

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got facing the issue when running npm install, but always throw error: npm ERR! Error: Unsupported platform: Windows_NT x64

I also delete node_module and package-lock of project and run npm install again, still get issue

Also go to the npm-cache and npm of node js, and run npm i and npm install, nothing changes

[image]

Please help, I am using visual studio code to run test

Comment: Have you considered raising an issue or pull request against the `near-sandbox` package? Or even searching for [an existing issue](https://github.com/near/sandbox/issues/36)?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, the `near-sandbox` package doesn't support Windows.

According to their [GitHub](https://github.com/near/sandbox) page, the following operating systems are currently supported:

> Intel-based Macs and Debian/Ubuntu-flavored Linux distros using Intel processors

The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) could help you out.